# PostgreSQL return result of funtion in loop

Tags: postgresql, function, loops, select, return

in my loop I would like to return the result of an SQL query here:

select mybd.service_offer_01 (rec.id_v2, $ 2, $ 3);
Do you have an idea ?

Thank you

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_price(param1 TEXT, param2 TEXT,param3 TEXT)
  RETURNS TABLE (
    id_v2 TEXT
    prix prix_type
  )

AS $$

do
$$
declare
    rec record;
begin
    for rec in select regexp_split_to_table($1,',') as id_v2
    loop
         select mybd.service_offre_01(rec.id_v2,$2,$3); 
    end loop;
end;
$$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code cannot to work from more reasons:

1. Syntax - the nesting `DO` statement is absolutely useless, and more - it block any result. There is not possibility to return anything from `DO` statement.
2. The result of plpgsql is realized by `RETURN` statement. For table function, like your, you should to use `RETURN NEXT` or `RETURN QUERY`. `RETURN NEXT` sends one row to output, `RETURN QUERY` sends a result of some query. It is well documented. Please, read doc - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html. The lot of pattern are described here - and documentation reading is only work for few hours. This is good investment :)

So your code can looks like (I have not detailed info about function `service_offre_01`):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_price(param1 TEXT, param2 TEXT,param3 TEXT)
RETURNS TABLE (id_v2 TEXT, prix prix_type)
AS $$
DECLARE rec record;
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN SELECT regexp_split_to_table($1,',') AS id_v2
  LOOP
     RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM mybd.service_offre_01(rec.id_v2,$2,$3); 
  END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```